# What's the easiest way to switch between floating point types?

Tags: c++, math, floating-point

I'm dealing with some calculations and would like to see which results will be obtained with `float` or `long double` instead of the default `double` precision. It should be costless way, without side effects, but now i'm not sure how to implement this: `std::pow<float>` function returns a double, also we have a functions like `powf`/`powl`, `expf`/`expl` and compiler doesn't allow implicit conversion from double-literals to float-literals.

I used simlpe project-wide `typedef long double real_t`, but this only worked for `double` and `long double` (narrowing float -> double literal implicit conversion breaks compilation). But it looks poor and now i just use `double` everywhere for safety. Maybe there are alternative math functions from Boost?

Comment: [`std::pow`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow) is not a template as you appear to suggest, and always returns `float` when both arguments are also `float`.

Comment: `std::pow` and function overloading is certainly the right tool, but I suspect you're passing an `int` as the second argument somewhere, in which case some arithmetic promotion rules apply. Assuming that's the case, have you tried something like `std::pow(someRealNumber, static_cast<real_t>(someIntegerPower)`?

Comment: i tried something like `auto y = std::pow<float>(b, e)`, but it's returned `double` and intellisense says it's constexpr function with (float, int) signature

Comment: `std::pow` is not a template.

Comment: @fumanchouz again, have you tried something like `std::pow(someRealNumber, static_cast<real_t>(someIntegerPower))` where the arguments both ensured to be `real_t`?

Comment: @alterigel there is no problem with integer power, it works without casting, but pow(float, int) returns double, so we'll have a conversion double -> float

Comment: @Casey `pow<float>` will compile with msvc and gcc

Comment: @Casey again, have you tried the code I suggested? Does it return `double` when `real_t` is `float`?

Comment: @alterigel yes, because it's part of standart since c++11 - there is no overloading pow(float, int) -> float, only pow(float, int) -> double, so if i change typedef to float, i'll should to change pow to powf

Comment: @fumanchouz I apologize if I sound condescending but do you know what `static_cast` does?

Comment: @fumanchouz The version you are referring to is in the overload set for [std::valarray](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray/pow) and is not intended to be used for what you are doing.

Comment: @Casey sorry for tagging you earlier, my comment was meant for OP

Comment: @alterigel no problem

Comment: @alterigel yes, but there is too many places which need to be replaced with static_cast

Comment: @fumanchouz if you're willing to instrument your entire code base like you're proposing to test floating point performance, you can probably afford a few `static_casts`. It should be easy to mostly automate the process

Comment: @alterigel it seems the only way, thanks for the thoughts